# More elegant way to return a sequence of numbers based on booleans?

Tags: r

Here's a sample of booleans I have as part of a data.frame:

`atest <- c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    FALSE)`

I want to return a sequence of numbers starting at 1 from each FALSE and increasing by 1 until the next FALSE.

The resulting desired vector is:

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1
```

Here's the code that accomplishes this, but I'm sure there's a simpler or more elegant way to do this in R. I'm always trying to learn how to code things more efficiently in R rather than simply getting the job done.

```
result <- c()
x <- 1
for(i in 1:length(atest)){
    if(atest[i] == FALSE){
        result[i] <- 1
        x <- 1
    } 
    if(atest[i] != FALSE){
        x <- x+1
         result[i] <- x
    }
}
```

Comment: Re-allocating ("growing") an object in a for loop is a big no-no in R.  It's about the slowest thing you can do.

Comment: I know I tried with an sapply but just wanted to get the basic logic out. Your solution is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using handy (but not widely-known/used) base functions:

```
> sequence(tabulate(cumsum(!atest)))
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1
```

To break it down:

```
> # return/repeat integer for each FALSE
> cumsum(!atest)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3
> # count the number of occurrences of each integer
> tabulate(cumsum(!atest))
[1] 10 10  1
> # create concatenated seq_len for each integer
> sequence(tabulate(cumsum(!atest)))
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1
```

Comment: I already +1'd, but I'd do it again as the explanation is really helpful!

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich +1 for this great solution; but it fails if the first element isn't `FALSE`: `sequence(tabulate(cumsum(!atest[-1])))`

Comment: @sgibb: I didn't try the OP's code before I answered, but I see it starts the first sequence at 2 if the first element isn't `FALSE`.  That seems inconsistent with their text, "I want to return a sequence of numbers starting at 1 from each FALSE and increasing by 1 until the next FALSE."

Comment: This is awesome. My data will always start with a FALSE. I've never used tabulate or sequence, only seq. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

Here is another approach using other familiar functions:

```
seq_along(atest) - cummax(seq_along(atest) * !atest) + 1L
```

Because it is all vectorized, it is noticeably faster than @Joshua's solution (if speed is of any concern):

```
f0 <- function(x) sequence(tabulate(cumsum(!x)))
f1 <- function(x) {i <- seq_along(x); i - cummax(i * !x) + 1L}
x  <- rep(atest, 10000)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f0(x), f1(x))
# Unit: milliseconds
#   expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
#  f0(x) 19.386581 21.853194 24.511783 26.703705 57.20482   100
#  f1(x)  3.518581  3.976605  5.962534  7.763618 35.95388   100

identical(f0(x), f1(x))
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Problems like these tend to work well with `Rcpp`. Borrowing @flodel's code as a framework for benchmarking,

```
boolseq.cpp
-----------

#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector boolSeq(LogicalVector x) {
  int n = x.length();
  IntegerVector output = no_init(n);
  int counter = 1;
  for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (!x[i]) {
      counter = 1;
    }
    output[i] = counter;
    ++counter;
  }
  return output;
}

/*** R
x <- c(FALSE, sample( c(FALSE, TRUE), 1E5, TRUE ))

f0 <- function(x) sequence(tabulate(cumsum(!x)))
f1 <- function(x) {i <- seq_along(x); i - cummax(i * !x) + 1L}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f0(x), f1(x), boolSeq(x), times=100)

stopifnot(identical(f0(x), f1(x)))
stopifnot(identical(f1(x), boolSeq(x)))
*/
```

`sourceCpp`ing it gives me:

```
Unit: microseconds
       expr       min        lq     median         uq       max neval
      f0(x) 18174.348 22163.383 24109.5820 29668.1150 78144.411   100
      f1(x)  1498.871  1603.552  2251.3610  2392.1670  2682.078   100
 boolSeq(x)   388.288   426.034   518.2875   571.4235   699.710   100
```

Less elegant, but pretty darn close to what you were writing with R code.