# Increasing sequence not equal

Tags: r

I cannot replicate the exact sequence of `x` that would generate shorter output `s` by about `20` observations, but it does happen. Why is this? How can I fix (assure) that it its length always equal to the base sequence `x`? Sometimes `x` and `s` differ by way more than just 2 observations (due to `cumsum`).

Example:

```
set.seed(123)
# this sequence length is equal (or close):
x <- diff(log(rnorm(500,5,1))); x[1:5] <- NA
# this sequence doesn equal; is shorter as the output `s`
x <- rnorm(500,0.1,0.1); x[1:5] <- NA
z <- ifelse(x<0,FALSE,ifelse(x>0,TRUE,NA))
g <- z[!is.na(z)]

s <- c(rep(NA,sum(is.na(z))), sequence(tabulate(cumsum(!g))))
s
length(x) # check length
length(s) # check length
```

So the length of output `s` is data dependent.

The aim so to add the output `s` to `x`; `data.frame(s,x)`

Comment: I don't understand what this question is asking at all.

Comment: I think `tabulate` strips off the 0 values.  Try with `table`

Comment: @David: please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820752/more-elegant-way-to-return-a-sequence-of-numbers-based-on-booleans/17820865#17820865

Comment: `length(c(rep(NA,sum(is.na(z))), sequence(table(cumsum(!g)))))
#[1] 500`

Comment: @akrun: yes, that's it, thank you! I thought about trying `table` but I didn't :)

Comment: @akrun: I'm sorry, I just thought I delete this question due to easy fix. So please submit your answer and I will accept it.  Maybe if you could include this-and-that, perhaps useful to some. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the `?tabulate`

> bin: a numeric vector (of positive integers), or a factor.  Long
>             vectors are supported.

So, either we convert to `factor` as the positive integers won't include 0 or we can use `table` which don't have that problem.

```
 s1 <- length(c(rep(NA,sum(is.na(z))), sequence(tabulate(factor(cumsum(!g))))))
 s1
 #[1] 500
```

Or using `table`

```
 s2 <- length(c(rep(NA,sum(is.na(z))), sequence(table(cumsum(!g)))))
 s2
 #[1] 500
```

which is equal to `length` of 'x'

```
length(x)
#[1] 500
```